# I need to split a string of text into two colors

Tags: html, css

I need to split the `<h1 class="brand-heading">DoesThat</h1>` portion of

```
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="brand-heading">DoesThat</h1>
          <p class="intro-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
           adipiscing elit. Nam at erat dui. Aliquam rutrum odio non ante 
           gravida, id efficitur est pellentesque. Morbi blandit leo quis 
           urna facilisis, et pretium ipsum vulputate.</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

into two different colors. "Does" needs to be one color, and "that" needs to be another color. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried yourself to accomplish this?  Also can you edit the HTML?  Are you looking for a particular type of solution?  CSS? Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/okahara/7hsp3LLj/

```
<h1 class="brand-heading"><span class="color1">Does</span> <span class="color2">That</span></h1>


.color1 {
  color: red
}

.color2 {
  color: blue
}
```

You can use two spans and give them both separate colors.

Answer (score 1):

I would change:

```
<h1 class="brand-heading">DoesThat</h1>
```

to:

```
<h1 class="brand-heading">Does<span class="color-class">That</span></h1>
```

Where `color-class` is based on your css. In Bootstrap it might be `text-primary` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to wrap it with a `span` tag. Otherwise using only css is not possible.

```css
.brand-heading{
  color: red;
}

.brand-heading span{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="brand-heading"><span>Does</span>That</h1>
          <p class="intro-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
           adipiscing elit. Nam at erat dui. Aliquam rutrum odio non ante 
           gravida, id efficitur est pellentesque. Morbi blandit leo quis 
           urna facilisis, et pretium ipsum vulputate.</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) or [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) ***(for info to any body thinking extra tag is needed ;) ) .***

example:

[`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
.brand-heading {
  position:relative;
  background:white;
}
.brand-heading:before {
  mix-blend-mode:screen;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  
  background:linear-gradient(to right, 
    tomato 2em,
    lime 2em)
  left  ;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="brand-heading">DoesThat</h1>
          <p class="intro-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
           adipiscing elit. Nam at erat dui. Aliquam rutrum odio non ante 
           gravida, id efficitur est pellentesque. Morbi blandit leo quis 
           urna facilisis, et pretium ipsum vulputate.</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

```css
.brand-heading {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, tomato 2em, lime 2em) ;
  background-clip: text;
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="brand-heading">DoesThat</h1>
          <p class="intro-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
           adipiscing elit. Nam at erat dui. Aliquam rutrum odio non ante 
           gravida, id efficitur est pellentesque. Morbi blandit leo quis 
           urna facilisis, et pretium ipsum vulputate.</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```